# JComboBox navigation in dropdown list selects the item

Tags: java, swing

This is my first question and I'm realy sorry for my English. I don't want to navigation in JComboBox's dropdown list show the selected item in the "JComboBox's main field" (sorry, don't know how to call it, see the images).

This is what happen when I navigate in list:

[image: JComboBox]

But I want something like this:

[image: JComboBox]

and when I press Enter or clicked on item, it appear in the main field.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import java.awt.*;

public class ComboTest {

JFrame frame;
JPanel panel;
String[] choices = new String[]{
        "Java",
        "Python",
        "C++",
        "PHP",
        "Perl"
};
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(choices);
JTextComponent textComponent;

public static void main(String[] args){
    new ComboTest();
}

public ComboTest() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();
    textComponent = (JTextComponent) comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent();

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    comboBox.setEditable(true);
    comboBox.setSelectedItem(null);

    panel.add(comboBox);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to zilk. Your answer helped me to solve this. The listener `addPopupMenuListener` doesn't work for me. But when I changed the `addPopupMenuListener` to `addItemListener`, everything worked fine.

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent itemEvent) {
            comboBox.getEditor().setItem(null);
            comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    super.keyPressed(e);
                    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                    {
                        comboBox.getEditor().setItem(itemEvent.getItem());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code block

```
   comboBox.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            //when Popupmenu is visible, remove the combobox editor text 
            comboBox.getEditor().setItem(null);

        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        }
    });
```